# Create 'Automatic copy to clipboard' javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want a page to copy some preset text to the clipboard for a user on load.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var copyText = document.getElementById("myInput");
  copyText.select();
  copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999)
  document.execCommand("copy");
  alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
  console.log(copyText.value)
}

function myClick() {
  document.getElementById("myButton").click();
}
```

```html
<body onload="myClick()">
    <input type="text" value="COPIED" id="myInput">
    <button onclick="myFunction()" id="myButton">Copy text</button>
</body>
```

The alert appears and the console logs the value - COPIED

But the text isn't actually copied to the clipboard. Clicking on the button 'Copy text' - does work?

Comment: Probably a safety mechanism, to prevent you from _overwriting_ what I might currently have in my clipboard, without even _asking_!

Comment: I'm happy to ask -but want to know how to get that permission :-)

Comment: @JayOram a permission is granted after a user-action. I'm afraid no auto-mechanism is at your dispose for the logical consequences mentioned in the first comment.

Comment: Can I ask for permission onload ??

Comment: No, you can not explicitly ask for any “permission” here. The button _is_ your way to “ask” whether or not the user wants to copy something into their clipboard – and _clicking_ the button would be their way to answer that question.

Comment: Thank you - T.J Crowder answered below as well - you need the user to click, which grants permission - no way to have it come up on load. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: @CBroe - Actually, there's a new experimental API associated with a permission.

Answer (score 4):

You can't put something in the user's clipboard except in response to an overt action of theirs — for instance, a button click. Think about it: You put something in your clipboard, browse a web page, and then click paste and something completely unexpected gets pasted. That's not okay, so browsers don't let you do it.

In a comment you've asked:

> Can I ask for permission onload ?

The recent [asynchronous clipboard API](https://www.w3.org/TR/clipboard-apis/) is associated with the [`"clipboard-write"` permission](https://w3c.github.io/permissions/#dom-permissionname-clipboard-write). For instance, this code works on page load when I run it from a [secure context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Secure_Contexts):

```
navigator.permissions.query({name: "clipboard-write"})
.then(({state}) => {
    console.log(`permission response: ${state}`);
    if (state === "granted") {
        const data = [new ClipboardItem({ "text/plain": new Blob([`The time is ${new Date()}`], { type: "text/plain" }) })];
        navigator.clipboard.write(data).then(
            () => {
                console.log("Clipboard write succeeded");
            },
            () => {
                console.error("Clipboard write failed");
            }
        );
    }
});
```

I'm slightly unhappy to see that neither Brave nor Chrome prompts me to grant the permission. Oddly, as far as I can tell, I have them configured to ask me when applications want access to the clipboard, but I don't get any prompt. Seems like a Chromium bug.

---

<opinion>
As a user, I would be ***very*** cross if a website wrote to my clipboard under any circumstances other than me clicking a button clearly labelled "Copy to clipboard" or similar. It would likely make me never visit that site again.
</opinion>

Comment: Is there a way to ask for permission on page load - rather than on click?

Comment: @JayOram load is authomatism - not a user-action (like i.e: a button Click event)

Comment: @JayOram - Actually, there's a newer experimental API associated with a permission.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - this was a working idea that moving from an email that has a call to action/button that says Copy code and visit 'URL' - then it would copy the code and go to the website, as you can't use Javascript inside the email to copy to the clipboard.